# How can I get the Average Running Speed of the app user through HealthKit?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, healthkit

I am trying to create an app that gets all sorts of health data, and displays it in a neat format. This is just a personal practice project to learn about Healthkit, and I could find lots of information about how to get the step count and calories on YouTube, but nothing about how to find the running speed of the user. I look on the documentation, but the docs are scarce for healthkit, unless I'm using them incorrectly.

```js
func fetchRunningStats(){
    let speed = HKQuantityType(.runningSpeed)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: .startOfDay, end: Date())
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: speed, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate) 
    {
        _, result, error in guard
        let quantity = result, error == nil 
        else {
            print("error fetching running speed")
            return
        }
        let speedValue = quantity.averageQuantity()
        let activity = Activity(title: "Speed", subtitle: "Running Speed", image: "figure.run", amount: "\(speedValue)", id: 0)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.activities["averagespeed"] = activity
            }
            print(speedValue)
        }
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

This is the function to grab the average running speed, but it keeps returning a HKStatistic object, and I don't know how to "unwrap" it to get the value inside.

Comment: What output is this giving you? `speedValue` should be an `HKQuantity` which is pretty simple (a value, and a unit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code.

First, you need to specify the `.discreteAverage` option in your `HKStatisticQuery` otherwise the query will not return the `averageValue` you are looking for.

Once you have the average value you can access it using `doubleValue(for: HKUnit)` - But, there is no intrinsic type for speed/velocity.

You can create the required `HKUnit` using `HKUnit.meter().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.second())` - ie m/s

```
func fetchRunningStats(){
    let speed = HKQuantityType(.runningSpeed)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: .startOfDay, end: Date())
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: speed, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.discreteAverage]) 
    {
        _, result, error in guard
        let quantity = result, error == nil 
        else {
            print("error fetching running speed")
            return
        }
        let speedValue = quantity.averageQuantity()
        let activity = Activity(title: "Speed", subtitle: "Running Speed", image: "figure.run", amount: "\(speedValue)", id: 0)
let speedQuantity = quantity.averageQuantity()
            
            let speedUnit = HKUnit.meter().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.second())
            
            if let speedValue = speedQuantity?.doubleValue(for: speedUnit) {
                print("Average speed=\(speedValue) m/s")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.activities["averagespeed"] = activity
                }
            }
        }
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I couldn't find help on this problem anywhere else. Your description was really good, I learned a lot.